# What does the GoldenGate OGG-01296 error mean?

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I have the next printed error:

```
OGG-01296 Error mapping from SCHEMA.TABLE to SCHEMA.TABLE.
```

It is the error of a pump. A Pump is getting a data from an extract with DDL.

What is the log I have to read? There is no errors in ggserr.log.
The error is got from 'view report PUMP'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `OGG-01296` represents a mismatch between the structure of the tables in source and target, making the mapping fail.

You can check following to resolve the issue:

1. add Primary key or Unique index in the table if not present in source and target, both.
2. make sure that the columns, Indexes, and constraints of a table in target and source are identical
3. run `ADD TRANDATA SCHEMA.TABLE`

Please correct all of the above issues if present and check if it works.

Hope, It will be helpful.

Cheers!!

Comment: I used ADD SCHEMATRANDATA SCHEMA